Submitting an existing block or form in a modal doesn't work
I am trying to open either the simplenews subsription block or the corresponding form in a modal. I tried with both the form using the formBuilder service or the exising plugin-block and in both cases I can successfully load and display the subsription block/form in the modal.
The problem now is, that when I enter an email address and try to subscribe i.e. submit the form it doesn't work. I am redirected to my controller ajax callback.
How can I make the form/block work correctly inside the modal?

can you add more info like code regarding how you load the form/block that seems working fine however on submission of form in modal not working , may be by analysing  code , others can suggest  solution of it

The standard approach is old-style Drupal with a form alter hook adding a submit handler where you redirect to a different Drupal route:
$form_state->setRedirect('<front>');

You'll find plenty of examples by searching this site or others.
However, looking at the module's code, the form is OOP style, so it would be a better approach to extend the contrib form class and override the submit method:
public function submitExtra(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)  {
  parent::submitExtra($form, $form_state);
  $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
}

Then you can override other things, too, to make a perfect form to place it in modals, like the variants you've already tried for pages and blocks.

I tried as you suggested: I extended the contrib form class and overwrote the submitExtra method as above. I used hook_pentity_type_build() to add my extended form class. This works. But the result is still the same. When submitting the form in the modal I get redirected to my controller ajax callback.
